# How do I throw an error in C# Lambda function that will trigger a cloudwatch error?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

So I thought Cloudwatch would pick up "Throw new Exception()" within a try catch block on my C# lambda function, but it doesn't appear to be doing that.

How can I trigger the error in the lambda function where cloud watch could tell it was an alarm?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HG51r.png)

Comment: CloudWatch does not pick up on anything or have a concept of errors. What exactly is your goal? Seeing an invocation error in the lambda metrics? Do you have a log filter which checks for errors in the logs and raises an alarm?

Comment: Yes, I figured it out, Thanks for your response.